# horizontal bar chart with date in y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like examples of how to plot values of mean, max, min for each date in a clustered horizontal bar chart.

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0, 25, 135000),
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 2, 0, 0, 57, 386000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 2, 0, 0, 59, 579000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 2, 0, 0, 27, 676000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 2, 0, 0, 25, 135000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 2, 0, 0, 26, 414000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 2, 0, 0, 28, 145000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 2, 0, 0, 26, 432000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 2, 0, 0, 27, 301000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 2, 0, 0, 27, 643000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 2, 0, 0, 27, 673000), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 2, 0, 0, 28, 294000)]
```

```
mean = [-10.246537396121893, 1.3039215686274515, 1.007462686567164,
-0.12771084337349403, -0.1932367149758454, -0.3196125907990315, 
-0.04128440366972498, -0.19950738916256117, -1.6319018404907975, 
-1.1532258064516134, -1.666666666666668, -2.3958333333333326]
```

```
max = [-8.0, 19.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

```
min = [-12.0, -7.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -7.0, -7.0]
```

I tried with the barh method  without success to have the dates showing the y-axis side.

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0, 25, 135000),
    datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 2, 0, 0, 57, 386000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 2, 0, 0, 59, 579000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 2, 0, 0, 27, 676000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 2, 0, 0, 25, 135000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 2, 0, 0, 26, 414000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 2, 0, 0, 28, 145000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 2, 0, 0, 26, 432000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 2, 0, 0, 27, 301000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 2, 0, 0, 27, 643000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 2, 0, 0, 27, 673000), 
    datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 2, 0, 0, 28, 294000)]

data_values = [
[-10.246537396121893, 1.3039215686274515, 1.007462686567164,
-0.12771084337349403, -0.1932367149758454, -0.3196125907990315, 
-0.04128440366972498, -0.19950738916256117, -1.6319018404907975, 
-1.1532258064516134, -1.666666666666668, -2.3958333333333326], #mean
[-8.0, 19.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], #max
[-12.0, -7.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -7.0, -7.0]]#min

width = 0.35
ind = arange(len(dates))

for i in range(len(data_values)):
    plt.barh(ind + width * i, data_values[i], width)
```

How to display dates on the y-axis side for each mean, max, min bars corresponding to the date ?  Thanks for help.

Comment: Suspect you might really want a box-plot here http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the effect you were looking for?

[image: horizontal bar]

The key is to use the `matplotlib.dates` module to properly format dates:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
datenum = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)

for i in range(-1,len(data_values)-1):
    ax.barh(datenum + i*5., data_values[i], height=5.)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d'))

plt.show()
```